# insert subelement to elementree python elementtree

Tags: python, elementtree

```
<project>
  <publisher>
     <plugin name="plot">
       <plots>
          <plot name = "xyz">
             <title> </title>
             <yaxis> </yaxis>
             <file type = "csv">
                 <label> </label>
                 <flags> </flags>
             </file>
             <group> </group>
          </plot>
          <plot name = "abc">
             <title> </title>
             <yaxis> </yaxis>
             <file type = "csv">
                 <label> </label>
                 <flags> </flags>
             </file>
             <group> </group>
          </plot>
        </plots>
      </plugin>
   </publisher>
</project>
```

I want to add one or more 'plot' elements depending on some inputs and update the values of the tags. I tried to use et.SubElement() but it doesnot copy the child's. Is there are way to do it?

Comment: similar to 'remove' which deletes all the children and grand children, is there a way to copy a exisitng element(along with its children) and append to the tree.

Comment: "depending on some inputs". What inputs?

Comment: depending on how many plots user what to add. If user mentions 4, then 4 plot elements along with the child needs to be added to the xml file.